# Composer --version error: This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm following the hyperledger composer setup here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html

but after installing composer I ran "composer --version" it gives the following error:

```
module.js:681
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^
Error: The module '/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report/api.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/node-report/index.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

Am i doing something wrong here?
Node version: v8.11.1
npm version: 6.0.0
System: ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS 64bit

The pre-requisites were installed following this page: 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and re-installing composer-cli?

Comment: Yes I did but same error.

Comment: Apparently i had some older version of node and npm installed before which is in conflict with what was installed by the script included in the tutorial. I had to clean up node and npm completely and run the script again which solved the issue

Comment: nice thats what i was suspecting. it sounded like composer or node-report was already installed and built for an earlier version